# How to read contents of next item in a list into a variable

Tags: python, file, csv

I'm trying to read the *next* field in each line, but I'm not sure how.

I can get current field, but I want the contents of field+1 on each line.

Right now i get "ipAddressCheck1" into ipAddressCheck1, but i want its contents to be "192.168.77.254" (the next field), for example.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import csv

###PARAMS.txt file contents...
###Remove first two ## each line, put into PARAMS.txt file
##"ipAddressCheck1","192.168.77.254"
##"ipAddressCheck2","microsoft.com"
##"ipAddressVerify1","8.8.8.8"
##"ipAddressVerify2","8.8.8.7"
##"nbrCycles","10"

#!/usr/bin/python3.4
#fjv101
import csv

###PARAMS.txt file contents...
###Remove first two ## each line, put into PARAMS.txt file
##"ipAddressCheck1","192.168.77.254"
##"ipAddressCheck2","microsoft.com"
##"ipAddressVerify1","8.8.8.8"
##"ipAddressVerify2","8.8.8.7"
##"nbrCycles","10"


def pgminit():
    filename = "PARAMS.txt"
    accessMode = "r"
    nbrCycles=0
    fjaddr1="blank"
    ipAddressCheck1="blank"
    ipAddressCheck2="blank"
    ipAddressVerify1="blank"
    ipAddressVerify2="blank"
    nbrCycles="0"
    with open(filename, accessMode) as myCSVFile:
        #Read file contents
        allRowsList = csv.reader(myCSVFile)
        print(allRowsList)
        for currentRow in allRowsList:
            for currentWord in currentRow:
              if currentWord == "ipAddressCheck1" :
                ipAddressCheck1 = currentWord
              elif currentWord == "ipAddressCheck2" :
                ipAddressCheck2 = "ipAddressCheck2"
              elif currentWord == "ipAddressVerify1" :
                ipAddressVerify1 = "ipAddressVerify1"
              elif currentWord == "ipAddressVerify2" :
                ipAddressVerify2 = "ipAddressVerify2"
              elif currentWord == "nbrCycles" :
                nbrCycles = 555

    print("ipAdddressCheck1=",ipAddressCheck1)
    print("ipAdddressCheck2=",ipAddressCheck2)
    print("ipAdddressVerify1=",ipAddressVerify1)
    print("ipAdddressVerify2=",ipAddressVerify2)
    print("nbrCycles=",nbrCycles)
    print("Press ENTER to continue...")
    fjChoiceNUL=input()

pgminit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used csv.DictReader instead, and set the first line with words
PARAM1 and PARAM2.  This becomes the field names, thus can locate
onto the desired field easily.  So far, works great.

The resultant output is in comment below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
#fjv102
import csv

##"PARAM1","PARAM2"
###PARAMS.txt file contents...
###Remove first two ## each line, put into PARAMS.txt file
##"ipAddressCheck1","192.168.77.254"
##"ipAddressCheck2","microsoft.com"
##"ipAddressVerify1","8.8.8.8"
##"ipAddressVerify2","8.8.8.7"
##"nbrCycles","10"

def pgminit():
    filename = "PARAMS.txt"
    with open(filename) as myCSVFile:
        #Read file contents
        allRowsList = csv.DictReader(myCSVFile)
        for currentRow in allRowsList:
            if currentRow['PARAM1'] == "ipAddressCheck1" :
              ipAddressCheck1 = currentRow['PARAM2']
            elif currentRow['PARAM1'] == "ipAddressCheck2" :
              ipAddressCheck2 = currentRow['PARAM2']
            elif currentRow['PARAM1'] == "ipAddressVerify1" :
              ipAddressVerify1 = currentRow['PARAM2']
            elif currentRow['PARAM1'] == "ipAddressVerify2" :
              ipAddressVerify2 = currentRow['PARAM2']
            elif currentRow['PARAM1'] == "nbrCycles" :
              nbrCycles = currentRow['PARAM2']

    print("ipAdddressCheck1=",ipAddressCheck1)
    print("ipAdddressCheck2=",ipAddressCheck2)
    print("ipAdddressVerify1=",ipAddressVerify1)
    print("ipAdddressVerify2=",ipAddressVerify2)
    print("nbrCycles=",nbrCycles)
    print("Press ENTER to continue...")
    fjChoiceNUL=input()

pgminit()
```

Comment: This is my resultant output...Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
ipAdddressCheck1= 192.168.77.254
ipAdddressCheck2= microsoft.com
ipAdddressVerify1= 8.8.8.8
ipAdddressVerify2= 8.8.8.7
nbrCycles= 10
Press ENTER to continue...